# 2 Questions: PHP code runs successfully on Apache webserver, but not on local EasyPHP?

Tags: php, easyphp

1: When I run this code (some unnecessary code omitted) on a webserver, it runs fine. I have an EasyPHP setup, and when I run the exact same code on that, I get the error:

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<<' (T_SL) in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-12.1\www\my portable files\part1.php on line 985`
(Line 985 is commented as such below)

2: Whenever I run this code on the webserver, it says that I do not have access to `$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]`, so I have to use "". While "" works, it doesn't validate correctly.

note: I cannot get the code blocks to format properly. The block(s) below should read as one continuous block.

```
function print_form() { 

echo <<<END         /*Line 985*/
<h1>Welcome to the player registration page. Please input the following:</h1> 


 <form action="$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]" method="post"> 

<div class="name"> 
Username: <input type="text" name="name" size="12"    /> <br /> 
</div> 


<div class="country"> 
Country: <select name="country"> 
<option value="">Select Country</option> 
<option value="AF">Afghanistan</option>  
...
       <option value="ZW">Zimbabwe</option>  
    </select>  
</div> 

<div class="xfire"> 
Xfire: <input type="text" name="xfire" /> <br /> 
</div> 


<div class="team"> 
Team: <input type="text" name="team" /> <br /> 
</div> 

<div class="tag"> 
Tag: <input type="text" name="tag" /> <br /> 
</div> 




<input type="hidden" name="stage" value="process"> 
 Submit Info: 
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/> 

</form>

END;
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
function print_form() { 
?>
<h1>Welcome to the player registration page. Please input the following:</h1>
...
<? } ?>
```

I think this way is much easier...

Comment: So remove the '<<<END' and END; altogether? Don't they parse the html? Is there a different way to parse the html?

Comment: remove `echo <<<END`, close the php code with `?>`, and put the html code. Then open the php code again and close the function.

Comment: Doesn't explain why easyphp is choking on a heredoc, which a perfectly valid PHP code sequence.

Comment: well, i'm not a php professional, I'm only a programmer. If something is not working I only try to find an alternative way to make it work...

Comment: ouch so you fix symptoms not the disease?

Comment: i think I just find an simple and creative way to fix the disease. Once I tried to use `<<<END` and `END`, and I had the same problem, then I started using like on my post above...

Comment: no the disease is the issue with heredoc, your just fixing the symptom.

Comment: anyway, it's fixed! why keeping discussing something is already solved? lol

Comment: some people like to see things done properly, obviously not you, lol.

Comment: Well, I really don't know why his code isn't working. do YOU know why? If so, please post an answer that could help him. Maybe he needs an quick and useful answer and my answer maybe can help him a lot. I'm not here to fight, and keep discussing here will not make his code work.

Comment: Sorry to be causing so much E-drama, but that solution isn't working either. The code I posted runs correctly on the webserver, just not in my local EasyPHP host. I don't think it is an issue with syntax, which is what my question was saying.

Comment: @JamesRoberts there's something fundamentally wrong with your local php install. Its having issues with valid syntax. I would be inclined to reinstall. Perhaps another WAMP stack, such as WAMPserver or XAMPP

Comment: Thank you Dagon. Do you have a suggestion for #2? I can reply later with the exact error when I'm near a webserver terminal.

Comment: @JamesRoberts open that as a new question, for best results. and include exact returned error message.